# Truffle migrate got stuck

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

---

### Issue

I ran the official example code: truffle migrate,and stuck there for a long long time:

## truffle migrate

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Deploying Migrations...
```

### Steps to Reproduce

I started my geth using command:

```
geth --port 3000 --networkid 58343 --nodiscover --datadir=./datadir --maxpeers=0  --rpc --rpcport 8543 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner"
```

myGenesis.json

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 16,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0
},
"difficulty": "400",
"gasLimit": "2000000",
"alloc": {
"f953e0323e6ef6fabe74a2a16ca633cdf512203a":{
"balance":"1000000000000000000000000"
}
}
}
```

truffle.js

```
module.exports = {
rpc: {
host:"localhost",
port:8543
},
networks: {
development: {
host: "localhost", //our network is running on localhost
port: 8543, // port where your blockchain is running
network_id: "*",
from: "0xf953e0323e6ef6fabe74a2a16ca633cdf512203a", // use the 
account-id generated during the setup process
gas: 1900000
        }
    }
};
```

Note: I unlocked the 0th account from geth console  and  did start mining at the time of  deploying . I checked the statuus using personal.listWallets() and found that rest all accounts are locked except the first one.

### Expected Behavior

Truffle migration should be have completed succeesfully

### Actual Results

Then I redeployed and I got this output
Using network 'development'.

```
`Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
 Deploying Migrations... 
 0x313ee101eb7b3f3e9eb49c08a3d45b926e68ff3c55f3f5bdc7b0359be75f5bef
 Migrations: 0x61ccc18e4e1e66086c0e9ceea8e45471b471d7f5
 Saving successful migration to network...
 ... undefined
 Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful 
 transactions manually.
 Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
 at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-
 linux-x64/ lib/node_modules/truffle/ 
 build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
 at /usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-
 x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build 
 /webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
 at /usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-
 x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-
 migrate/index.js:225:1
at /usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/packages/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

### Environment

- Operating System: Ubuntu
- Ethereum client: Geth 1.8.14-stable-316fc7ec
- Truffle version (`truffle version`): v4.1.14 (core: 4.1.14)
- node version (`node --version`):v8.9.4
- npm version (`npm --version`): 5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not signing your transaction. After it hasn't been signed for a long time, you are getting that error.

Since you are using Geth and pointing to your localhost, you must unlock your account that is sending the transaction *before* you run `truffle migrate`.  This can be done by using the flags `geth --unlock <YOUR_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> --password <YOUR_PASSWORD>`.

Comment: I had unlocked my account using command: 
    `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])` before truffle migrate, still was getting this error.                                                                                                        **The issue is that you are not signing your transaction. After it hasn't been signed for a long time, you are getting that error.** - Not clear about this though. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: From the documentation [personal.unlockaccount](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_unlockaccount) the account is unlocked for 5 minutes after that you have to unlock again. You can use 0 as duration to unlock until you quit geth.